# MYSQL - Grouping & Max?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that produces the following results:

```
userid  statusid  no      name    area    month    year    dateupdated
62      2         763     ABCD    Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      7    2012    2013-11-26 15:10
62      2         869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 14:50
61      1         763     ABCD    Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 14:50
54      1         200     ABCDE   US         12    2013    2013-11-26 21:02
32      2         200     ABCDE   US         12    2013    2013-11-26 21:03
```

I want to be able to show the latest 'no' per row. I have tried using `max(dateupdated)`, but still shows all the records. I've also tried grouping, but also no luck.

I only need to see the latest record determined by the `dateupdated`.

Can anyone please assist me?

Comment: You need to retrieve the ``statusid`` of a max(dateudpated) in a sub query, and use that to return the complete row with the ``no`` value

Comment: I need to show the latest row of each 'no'. I want to determine the latest row via 'dateupdated'. for example,  the 'no' 763 has two records, i want to only show the latest entry per 'dateupdated'

Comment: I want to retrieve all the records, but where the 'no' is the same, only show the latest record from 'dateupdated'

Comment: I used the following code: 
'GROUP BY name'
'ORDER BY max(dateupdated) DESC'

This did exactly what i wanted. 
Thanks to everyone for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6631f/9)**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON t2.dateupdated > t1.dateupdated
AND t1.no = t2.no
WHERE t2.no IS NULL
```

Result:

```
| USERID | STATUSID |  NO |  NAME |   AREA | MONTH | YEAR |                     DATEUPDATED |
|--------|----------|-----|-------|--------|-------|------|---------------------------------|
|     62 |        2 | 763 |  ABCD | Brazil |     6 | 2013 | November, 26 2013 15:28:00+0000 |
|     62 |        2 | 869 |   ABC | Brazil |     6 | 2013 | November, 26 2013 15:28:00+0000 |
|     32 |        2 | 200 | ABCDE |     US |    12 | 2013 | November, 26 2013 21:03:00+0000 |
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you might be helped by something like this:

```
select * from mytable where dateupdated = (select max(dateupdated) from mytable);
```

EDIT:

Based on your clarification, you need in that case a correlated subquery.  I haven't tried this, but perhaps something like:

```
select * 
  from mytable a 
 where dateupdated = (select max(dateupdated) from mytable where no = a.no);
```

Comment: I think he wants it also by userid, etc, but I am not sure

Comment: if i have these two records : 
62      1   869     ABC     Brazil      7    2012  2013-11-26 15:10
62      2   869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013  2013-11-26 15:28

I only want to show the latest entry by date. It's like a grouping of some sort

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, but unfortunately still shows both records, doesn't should the latest updated 'dateupdated' record only

Comment: Hmm, the above should show only one row per unique "no" value unless you have more than one row for a particular "no" value where the max dateupdated is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table    
ORDER BY dateupdated DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Last for every no: (Is this what you want ?)

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table t2 
                 WHERE t1.no = t2.no 
                 AND t2.dateupdated > t1.dateupdated)
```

Comment: This will only show one record. I need to show all records, and where the 'no' exists, only show the latest record from the dateupdated

Comment: @user3040483 Edited: I add query: For every no return newest record.

Comment: Thanks, i only have one table? you make mention of 2 tables?

Comment: @user3040483 it is same table (table t1 and table t2), but with different aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Tag along a LIMIT 1; at the end of your query and sort descending.